# lite-uploader won't work with multiple files

Tags: javascript, file, upload, odoo

With the following setup

```
file_obj = $('#files');
file_obj.liteUploader({
    script: "/upload",
    rules: {
        allowedFileTypes: "application/pdf",
        maxSize: 100*1024*1024,
    }
})
file_obj.change(function () {
    $(this).data("liteUploader").startUpload();
});
```

and this html input:

```
<input type="file" name="files" multiple id="files" required="True"/>
```

it still continue to upload just the first file.
In the serverside script (which is in python: I am using OpenERP/Odoo), I see there's only one file as well.
I also tried to set singleFileUploads to true, but still the server is called once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is server side.

I was accessing the *files* field this way

```
@http.route(['/upload'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def upload(self, **args):
    files = args['files']
```

But with multiple files *args* contained only the first.
Then I noticed that inside request.httprequest.stream the size was a little bigger than the sum of uploaded files and with further investigation I discovered that I could obtain all files by using instead:

```
    files = request.httprequest.files.getlist('files')
```

Which works from 1 to n files